# Algorithm to compare two curves

Tags: c++, graph, comparison

I have developed an application in `Qt` using c++. The software will be used with a spectrometer device using which the user can view the spectrum of any chemical solution in our `GUI` Application.

We are using a `camera sensor` in which each wavelength of light will fall on particular pixel of the camera sensor. The user just need to see the values at their respective wavelength and therefore, I need a algorithm to map pixel to a particular wavelength. Since, there will be some unpredictable offset in each device, we need to calibrate every device we have.

I have a graph (`2-D array`) having pixel number on `X-Axis` and intensity value on `Y-axis` for a known solution. We will be having another graph stored in `csv` format which will have intensities at their respective wavelength. These two graphs needs to be compare (their curve will be similar) and we need to find a mapping of pixels to wavelength from that comparison.

**What I have done so far**

Earlier, we were considering 5 points in a known graph and then, we were finding those 5 points in our unknown graph using their intensities. Then, I was just mapping the pixel number to wavelength using Linear interpolation.

**What is my target**

I want to make the algorithm independent of sightly difference between known and unknown graph. Known graph and unknown graph may have some offset in Y-axis or may be scaled slightly. I am not sure for right kind of algorithm to use in my application.

Comment: If the scale is non-linear then 5 points will give a better result, but if it is a linear scale so all you need to know the range and use interpolation. You can incorporate scaling which only changes your range.